# Spring boot backend with angular frontend

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot backend and an angular frontend and now i want to use sprint boot to run on 8080 with its home page showing index.html(from angular).

I have created dist folder in angular using ng build --prod command and copied into (src/main/resources/static) folder.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56BHr.png)

In addition to this i read many stackoverflow posts about this and tried to create a war file by adding

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in pom.xml(Though i do not know how to create war)
In fact it created a war file(AIeDD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) in target folder.
Some post said to deploy the war on tomcat server but i do not know how to do it.

Now i do not what to do now ??

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cdac</groupId>
    <artifactId>AIeDD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AIeDD</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options, as with all Spring-Applications. You can either package it as war (without a bundled applicationserver) and deploy it on one. Or you can just package it as a jar (so called fat-jar) and deliver it with a bundled applicationserver. The default one is tomcat.

Then you can just keep your build process: creating a dist folder and copy contents into your resources folder. The controller you have then just returns the "path" to the files as string. An alternative is using a concrete maven plugin called "buildfrontend-maven-plugin". With this one you can just build your jar and maven takes care of the build of the angular app.

[Spring-Boot with Angular](https://medium.com/@majdasab/integrating-an-angular-project-with-spring-boot-e3a043b7307b)